# RSAT : Samba 4 Server not operational

Tags: windows, samba, active-directory, domain, kerberos

Samba 4 now supports GPO and management through the Active Directory Windows console. But, when I open it after installation, I cannot access the server nor the domain.

The message returned is that my domain controller is "not operational".

I followed several guides:

- https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Installing_RSAT_on_Windows_for_AD_Management
- https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO#Testing_DNS

My DNS server answers well to requests. But I wonder if the problem comes from Windows 7 and its compatibility with Samba 4 or from other network services (DNS, WINS, etc.).

My Samba server is a domain server which my windows 7 station has joined. My server also provides services for DNS, DHCP, NTP, WINS, SMB, Kerberos (samba internal), and printing.

I can authenticate without problems. I heard that the issue could be related to Kerberos. What do you think?

I'm using openSUSE 13.1 with Samba 4.1.17.

Was I wrong to choose Samba over an LDAPv3 based directory?

Comment: For future reference, I've found SLES to be better for doing samba on as opposed to OpenSuSE.

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I recommend Ubuntu for this kind of project because it supports GPO on the contrary on a lot of distributions.

Comment: Samba 4 does GPO.